# Posting PHP arrays to file

Tags: php, arrays

Hi my PHP is good but one thing i never get is arrays but i know how handy they are and thats why i'm going to use them.
Here's my problem:

my form is this :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<INPUT TYPE=CHECKBOX"." "."name"."="."\"to[]\""."    "."value=\""."0".$row['cnumber']."\" >".$row['cname']."<br>"."<br>";
} ?>
```

Firstly is this okay?? is "to[]" the right way to do it??

Okay then it is posted to another page:

```
$to = $_POST['to'][];
```

now the problem is that when I check it:

```
if (empty($to) {
header ("Location: /sms_error.php");
}
```

it says its empty and goes to sms_error.php

finally if you are interested this is what i do with the array:

```
 foreach ($to as $to) {
 /* code */
 }
```

Is this okay aswell??

Thanks in advance,
Niall

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$to = $_POST['to'][];
```

with

```
$to = $_POST['to'];
```

Comment: try doing a var_dump($to) after this line.

Comment: If none of the check boxes the returned `array` will be `empty`

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a quite good [documentation of arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Also [*Variables From External Sources*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) might be worth a read for you.

---

Now to your problem, step by step:

The way you create the HTML is very unclear. There is too much unnecessary string concatenation. It is better to not `echo` HTML but embed PHP in HTML:

```
<?php while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="to[]" value="0<?php echo $row['cnumber']; ?>">
    <?php echo $row['cname']; ?>
    <br>
    <br>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

It could very well be that you make some mistake regarding the quotes in your original code.

---

If you create the HTML correctly, then `$_POST['to']` will contain an array of values. You can check whether the array is empty or not with [**`empty($_POST['to'])`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

If you want to assign the array to a variable, then do:

```
$to = $_POST['to'];
```

---

<del>You are overriding `$to` in your `foreach` loop, which means that at the next iteration, `$to` does not point to an array anymore but to the first entry of the array.</del> Your `foreach` loop will override the array after the loop finished. `$to` will point to the last element of the array afterwards. This makes your code quite confusing. It is better to use another variable name:

```
foreach($to as $value) {

}
```

Comment: the reason i echo html is that there isn't a set number of input checkboxs.. it depends on how many 'contacts' a user has

Comment: i changed the names thanks, the code now runs to the end (i know because it then redirects) but the code above isn't executed and it doesn't go back and use the next value.. any ideas why??

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing `$to = $_POST['to'][];` to `$to = $_POST['to'];`, change if `(empty($to) {` to `if (empty($to)) {`

Comment: yeah no see there is other variables been checked there and the ( ) is around all of them

Comment: Are you sure the other variables are causing the redirection to sms_error?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably on php 5 or newer...

Since PHP 5, empty is not going to give you the correct result. Rather you must use isset().

eg: isset($to)

Comment: yeah i am maybe that is it.. but i've used empty before??

Comment: Like I said, since version 5, you ought to use isset. Check this out: (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: Where does it say you have to use `isset` instead of `empty` for arrays? The docs clearly say *The following things are considered to be empty: (...) array() (an empty array)*.

Answer (score 0):

you may have many input elements with different name?

if so, you can set $i=0 outside, then in your while loop, you can then set "\"to$i\"". At the end of loop, don't forget $i++.

Then $to = $_POST;
foreach ($to as $value) 
{
     /* code */
}